# delete specific user record from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with five columns in mysql database. i have designed an android app where the user can delete his/her record but i dont want the user to tamper with another persons record.(id(pk),commid,name,portfolio,contact,address)

I used the sql delete statement to delete the specific user record which was successfully but when the user inputs another id into the editText box i provided in the android app he is able to delete another persons record.

$connect  = mysqli_connect($host,$db_user,$db_password,$db_name);
    $id = $_POST["id"];

```
$query = "DELETE FROM community_entry where id='$id'";
```

Record gets deleted successfully for any number the user tries

Comment: Why would you give the user the choice of which record to delete? You know the user (because they are logged in) so YOU can be to one who sends the delete command with the user's id; don't ask the user for it!

Comment: Unless there are specific legal obligations to fulfil, its best not to allow users to delete information from the database. Instead allow them to update data to display as 'hidden'.

Comment: @ Strawberry  allow them to update data to display as 'hidden'                                     what do you mean by displaying as hidden

Comment: @ Caius Jard Why would you give the user the choice of which record to delete          I actually queried all of that users information in a table which i showed in table layout  of my android app so that whatever record he doesnt want he can delete it

Comment: Have a column called hidden with a default value of 0. When a user 'deletes', just change this value to 1.

Comment: @ Strawberry When a user 'deletes', just change this value to 1                           how will it protect another persons record from being deleted from the table

Comment: @joe You first need to read about authenticating a user; using the username to hold a login session is not okay. Send a unique, voidable token after successful login like PHP's inbuilt session handling. Then read about basic SQL injection, never put raw GET/POST/cookie data into a query. Then serve only records that a user can delete and show a checkbox for each one, not a text input field, then delete only records that match both the IDs selected by checkbox *and* the user ID you're storing server-side that correlates to the login token. There's no reason to expose those internal record IDs.

Comment: @Walf Thats Great Thank You very much.

Answer (score 1):

A better approach will be first to check if the user who is requesting to perform the delete operation is the same user whose ID has been passed. If that is true then let the user delete his account else you can return a "Not authorised" error.

Comment: A better approach will be first to check if the user who is requesting to perform the delete operation is the same user whose ID has been passed. If that is true then let the user delete his account else you can return a "Not authorised" error.                                                                                                     Please can you give me the code for checking this

Comment: When you are making a API call from your android app to the back-end what are the data that you are passing apart from userID? There must be some token which you might have created when a user logs in and that must be saved in the backed. How are you doing all this?

Comment: When you are making a API call from your android app to the back-end                                                                                                                             I took the users username and stored it in shared preferences in the android app.But now in the android app my post request is a value which i want the user to pass into my php script inorder to delete that specific record he doesnt want.So the php script just waits for that number to process it in the sql query

Comment: A better approach will be first to check if the user who is requesting to perform the delete operation is the same user whose ID has been passed         will try this approach and see how it turns out